# ios MagicalRecord sorting. Need a list of section headers

Tags: ios, uitableview, magicalrecord

I have a Core Data model accessed using MagicalRecord. I use this code to get a tableview sorted and grouped by categories:

```
frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"activityCategory,activityName"
                                  ascending:YES withPredicate:nil
                                    groupBy:@"activityCategory"
                                   delegate:nil];
```

The resulting tableview looks like this:

[image]

In another view, I use the same data, but this time want only a list of the section headers, represented by the attribute "activityCategory". I expected it to be a simple matter, but not so. This code, for example:

```
frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"activityCategory"
                              ascending:YES withPredicate:nil
                                groupBy:nil
                               delegate:nil];
```

yields this:

[image]

Instead, what I want is just a list of the categories (singularly), the attributes that provide the section headers in the first example. I tried a couple of other configurations, but realized I was just throwing stuff against the wall to see if it would stick. The documentation for MagicalRecord, as excellent as the framework is, is lamentably scant.

Can someone please point me at the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you'll need to configure your fetch request a bit more before firing the fetched results controller. MagicalRecord uses a naming convention such that if you change find to request, it'll instead return the NSFetchRequest object. So, for your case here, you'll need something like

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [ListActivity MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"activityCategory" ascending:YES inContext:context];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                          managedObjectContext:context
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                     cacheName:nil];
[frc MR_performFetch];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your code, adding a context, but got this error: "No visible @interface for 'NSFetchedResultsController' declares the selector 'MR_performFetch'" I also can't find any Quick Help on that selector. Have I lost a link to MagicalRecord?

Comment: It could be that method isn't public, I'm referencing the latest code, but I know that method is in there; crack open the source and have a look.

Comment: The method is indeed there, but for some reason the linker's not finding it. Or perhaps there's another problem. I've tried cleaning it, checked that the relevant file (NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m) in listed in Build Phases, ensured that "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h" is imported in the "-Prefix.pch" file and restarted Xcode. Still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider having a `ListActivityCategory` entity as well as storing the category as a String on `ListActivity`

That way you could fetch those instead of haven to 'unique' across all the returned `ListActivity` objects

Comment: I'm new to Core Data and to MagicalRecord. Are you suggesting a relationship between entities in the data model? If so, sounds workable, but I've never done it. Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: I'm sure there are many good tutorials out there if you google.

Comment: I know, Mike, and I've been watching Simon Allardice's course on Lynda.com. At the moment, I'm trying to make a decision on which path to take--correct the error with the approach suggested by casademora or create a new entity, which also sounds promising. I'll post the solution when I clear it up. Thanks!